# Django Rest Framework: POST object with id

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Is it possible to POST a new object while also specifying its id instead of auto incrementing? This is a one time import and the database id sequence would be corrected afterward.

```
class TestModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = TestModel
        fields = ('id', 'name')

class TestModelViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = TestModel.objects.all()
    serializer_class = TestModelSerializer

import requests
def test_post(endpoint):
    data = {
        "id": 30,
        "name": "Test",
    }
    r = requests.post(endpoint, data=data)
    print(r.status_code, r.reason)

test_post('http://localhost:8000/api/test_model/30/')
>>> 405 Method Not Allowed

test_post('http://localhost:8000/api/test_model/')
>>> 201 Created
```

`201 Created` creates a new object but with the next id in sequence instead of the desired id.

I've also tried `r = requests.put('http://localhost:8000/api/test_model/30/', data=data)` but get `404 Not Found`

Comment: When you add `id` to the end of the url it means you allready have the object, so if you try `POST` create the object you get an error becase not allowed to create the same object twice. And when you try `put` you catch correct error because the object does not exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could work but i'm not sure, I believe django-rest is reading from your django model that id is an auto-increment field, and hence doesn't create with the id provided. But it could work if you specify it explicitly as an integer field.

```
class TestModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    id = serializers.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        model = TestModel
        fields = ('id', 'name')
```